# How to search whole solr index?

Tags: php, solr

I import data from database directly into the solr index. Now I want to search it using [php-solr-client](http://code.google.com/p/solr-php-client/). Now I want to search it:

```
$offset = 0;
$limit = 10;

$queries = array(
    'details:Server'
); 

$response = $solr->search( $query, $offset, $limit );
```

For now I can only search when I specify the field, e.g. `details`. Is there a way to search all fields at a time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you omit the `details:`, doesn't it search all fields that are indexed?

Otherwise, you can always combine multiple fields in one query like this:

`details:Server OR field2:Server OR field3:Server`

EDIT: Regarding default field to search, specify a "dummy" field that would be populated with multiple values:

```
<field name="text" type="text" indexed="true" stored="false" multiValued="true"/>
```

Then have copyField entries for all fields that would be searched:

```
<copyField source="title" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="akatitle" dest="text"/>
<copyField source="year" dest="text"/>
```

And finally, specify that this field should be the default one:

```
<defaultSearchField>text</defaultSearchField>
```

That should work.

Comment: Not using it at all, just `Server`, I think that is valid Lucene query syntax.

Comment: when I leave out the field name I get no search result, was strange for me too

Comment: Then I'm guessing your documents aren't configured properly, I believe you can flag your fields to be searchable by default.

Comment: How do I do that? What needs to be configuered?

Comment: This is what I've done. Maybe you can specify multiple defaultFields, haven't tried it.