# Apache solr search is not working when i give the criteria q=value to search

Tags: apache, solr

Apache solr search is not working when i give the criteria q='value to search'. This is working fine when i gave q='*:*' and it fetches all the result.

I am using the Apache solr version 4.7.0

Comment: There's a lot here that you haven't explained, which I imagine is the reason for the down votes. I suggest you edit your question to add more detail. If you add the argument "&echoParams=all" to your query, the result will include more information about your search that may help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to search whole solr index?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5449727/how-to-search-whole-solr-index)

Answer (score 1):

The question needs more information.

yet .. the reason for not returning data could be the following potential reasons

1. Did you use the default query field df>text or did you edit in the solrconfig.xml?

> ```
> <lst name="defaults">
>       <str name="echoParams">explicit</str>
>       <int name="rows">10</int>
>       <str name="df">text</str>
>     </lst>
> ```

If the default is text field, did you populate the data into the field name "text" in schema.xml ?

1. If the default field is something else, dod you populate that field?

With the above clues you should be able to solve out.